# extracting zips, parsing files and flattening out to CSV

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm trying to maximize the performance of the following task:

- Enumerate directory of zip files
- Extract zips in memory looking for `.json` files (handling nested zips)
- Parse the `json` files
- Write properties from `json` file into an aggregated `.CSV` file

The TPL layout I was going for was:

```
producer -> parser block -> batch block -> csv writer block
```

With the idea being that a single producer extracts the zips and finds the json files, sends the text to the parser block which is running in parallel (multi consumer). The batch block is grouping into batches of 200, and the writer block is dumping 200 rows to a CSV file each call.

Questions:

- The longer the jsonParseBlock `TransformBlock` takes, the more messages are dropped. How can I prevent this?
- How could I better utilize `TPL` to maximize performance?

  ```
  class Item
  {
      public string ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  class Demo
  {
      const string OUT_FILE = @"c:\temp\tplflat.csv";
      const string DATA_DIR = @"c:\temp\tpldata";
      static ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions parseOpts = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { SingleProducerConstrained=true, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8, BoundedCapacity = 100 };
      static ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions writeOpts = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 100 };

      public static void Run()
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.ProcessorCount} processors available");
          _InitTest(); // reset csv file, generate test data if needed
          // start TPL stuff
          var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
          // transformer
          var jsonParseBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Item>(rawstr =>
          {
              var item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(rawstr);
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15); // the more sleep here, the more messages lost
              return item;
          }, parseOpts);

          // batch block
          var jsonBatchBlock = new BatchBlock<Item>(200);

          // writer block
          var flatWriterBlock = new ActionBlock<Item[]>(items =>
          {
              //Console.WriteLine($"writing {items.Length} to csv");
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              foreach (var item in items)
              {
                  sb.AppendLine($"{item.ID},{item.Name}");
              }
              File.AppendAllText(OUT_FILE, sb.ToString());
          });

          jsonParseBlock.LinkTo(jsonBatchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
          jsonBatchBlock.LinkTo(flatWriterBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

          // start doing the work
          var crawlerTask = GetJsons(DATA_DIR, jsonParseBlock);
          crawlerTask.Wait();
          flatWriterBlock.Completion.Wait();
          Console.WriteLine($"ALERT: tplflat.csv row count should match the test data");
          Console.WriteLine($"Completed in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0} secs");
       }

      static async Task GetJsons(string filepath, ITargetBlock<string> queue)
      {
          int count = 1;
          foreach (var zip in Directory.EnumerateFiles(filepath, "*.zip"))
          {
              Console.WriteLine($"working on zip #{count++}");
              var zipStream = new FileStream(zip, FileMode.Open);
              await ExtractJsonsInMemory(zip, zipStream, queue);
          }
          queue.Complete();
      }

      static async Task ExtractJsonsInMemory(string filename, Stream stream, ITargetBlock<string> queue)
      {
          ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream);
          foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
          {
              if (entry.Name.EndsWith(".json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
              {
                  using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open(), Encoding.UTF8))
                  {
                      var jsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                      await queue.SendAsync(jsonText);
                  }
              }
              else if (entry.Name.EndsWith(".zip", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
              {
                  await ExtractJsonsInMemory(entry.FullName, entry.Open(), queue);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

### Update1

I've added `async`, but it is not clear to me how to wait for all the dataflow blocks to complete (new to c#, async and tpl).  I basically want to say, "keep running until all of the queues/blocks are empty".  I've added the following 'wait' code, and appears to be working.

```
// wait for crawler to finish
crawlerTask.Wait(); 
// wait for the last block
flatWriterBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

Comment: Just FYI: I'm seeing about a 1.7x improvement over single threaded performance on a 4 core machine.

Comment: The completion looks ok as-is. Just know that the `Wait` is going to block, you could change `Run` to be an `async Task` instead and let your caller move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short your posting and ignoring the return value. You've got two options: add an unbound `BufferBlock` to hold all your incoming data or `await` on `SendAsync`, that will prevent any messages from being dropped.

```
static async Task ExtractJsonsInMemory(string filename, Stream stream, ITargetBlock<string> queue)
{
    var archive = new ZipArchive(stream);
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.Name.EndsWith(".json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var jsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                await queue.SendAsync(jsonText);
            }
        }
        else if (entry.Name.EndsWith(".zip", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            await ExtractJsonsInMemory(entry.FullName, entry.Open(), queue);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to pull the async all the way back up, but this should get you started.

Comment: I've added the `async` updates and it all seems to be working - no messages dropped.  Not 100% sure I'm properly waiting for the processing to complete though.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN, about the [`DataflowBlock.Post<TInput>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194836.aspx) method:

> Return Value
>   Type: `System.Boolean`
>   **true** if the item was accepted by the target block; otherwise, **false**.

So, the problem here is that you're sending your messages without checking, can the pipeline accept another one, or not. This is happening because of your options for blocks:

```
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 100 }
```

and this line:

```
// this line isn't waiting for long operations and simply drops the message as it can't be accepted by the target block
queue.Post(jsonText);
```

Here you're saying that the processing should be **postponed** until the input queue length is equal to `100`. In this case either the MSDN or @StephenCleary in his [Introduction to Dataflow](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html) series suggest simple solution:

> However, it’s possible **to throttle a block by limiting its buffer size**; in this case, **you could use [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync.aspx)** to (asynchronously) wait for space to be available and then place the data into the block’s input buffer.

So, as @JSteward already suggested, you can introduce the infinite buffer between your workers to avoid the message dropping, and this is a general practice to do that, as checking the result of the `Post` method could block the producer thread for a long time.

The second part of the question, about the performance, is to use the `async`-oriented solution (which will perfectly fit with [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync.aspx) method usage), as you use I/O operations all the time. Asynchronous operation is basically a way to say the program "start doing this and notify me when it's done". And, as [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) for such operations, you will gain by freeing up the thread pool for other operations you have in your pipeline.

PS: @JSteward had provided your a good sample code for this approaches.

Comment: I had originally tried an unbounded buffer, but was running out of memory as the consumers couldn't seem to keep up.  Working on the async version now.

Comment: @lifebythedrop yeah, unbounded capacity for buffer could lead to memory problems, in that case you either create a blocking thread to post messages or do async. Good luck with that.